# Regex separate numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

> $7$7+41+11+11+4 2+21+41+71+13!

Numbers correspond to dictionary string indexes, dollar sign means the letter is uppercase, plus sign means double-digit. The rest of the characters will stay.

I put together this pattern:

```
[$][\d]|[\d][x(?=+)][x(?!\d)]|[\d]|[\D]
```

However, it will not find `$7+4` and will split it up to `$7`, `+`, `4`.

Any hints or advice is welcome.

**Edit**

Given the following:

- The subject `$741+11+11+4 2+21+41+71+13!`
- The dictionary `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

The result I expect is `Hello world!`. Each set of characters corresponds to an index in the dictionary. So `$7` means uppercase of the character in the `7`th position in the dictionary (`H`). `4` points to the `4`th element in the dictionary (`e`), and `1+1` points to the `11`th element in the dictionary (`l`).

Comment: uppercase numbers? what?

Comment: `+` is a special regex character and needs to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Expected result?!

Comment: Wow that's a weird looking regex. You made everything a set...

Comment: @shmosel not when the whole regex is in a set :/

Comment: Dictionary string is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and result would be in case of "$741+11+11+4 2+21+41+71+13!" => Hello world!.

Comment: @KalevKilumets how?

Comment: Please, have a look on how to use [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: $7 is seventh letter from dictionary and uppercase, 4 is fourth letter, 1+1 is eleventh and so on@ctwheels

Comment: Ok I get it now, use `\$?\d(?:\+\d)?|.`

Comment: In your regex what is `x` supposed to mean?

Comment: @ctwheels, Thank you! I found a Java Regular Expression Tester and got the examples from there. Therefor x actually doesn't mean anything

Comment: Don't post important info as comment. If question require clarifying use [edit] option and put all necessary information there so people wouldn't need to search for it in comments to understand what question is about. Also few examples of input and expected results (with explanation why you think they should be expected, and what would be incorrect) would be nice.

Comment: @KalevKilumets I have a working solution, but, unfortunately, the question is currently closed. See my next comment for the link (the link is too long to post in this comment)

Comment: https://tio.run/##dVFNj9MwED0nv2I22oOjgrVdVlpBFVWrhcMekJBWnAgH13ETZx3b2JN@AP3txUndFrZCSjz287z3ZsYtW7G3xgrdVi/v93vZWeMQ2oDSHqWiTtRiQz8z5I1ws/Q/918YonB6lqZcMe/hqRJGi/RXmth@oSQHjwxDWBlZQcekBvKMTur623dgrvY5YOPM2h@EFdM1/bThwqI0Ok2CTLKUmik4kMD3i1ZwhAKy6/u76WQ6fndwO7kNYTq5D@d3V9nsNa@SfFBkbjtQ2YJXYlk3sn1RnTb2h/PYr9ab7c9L5tjmQCJleT0vy4rMP5TlJGzyef6bBsKJEWcBNsbiiFBuOiuVIKNYfvaI0w2DOcTiyKURIbHhfLRZN0EESLyjQaMieQ7DlBK5POG1M70l0xyuCtC9UjEjkRohUMZ2njSGWhy1zHkRDhfk8L5WMS4elCJZWX6cZG8gy/Kx@CThDXMwLIzjWPd5wHSAH5CMTjFdLuHSIObd5FAMz5mdgWPByd8Oj8c9RfPVWuEemRfklBGdduP6vPUoOmp6pDa8Ir5O24FQXkSXi@R/K72JPQ/K4d@lu/3@Dw

Comment: @KalevKilumets I'll post it as an answer if your question is reopened

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make this

```
"$7$7+41+11+11+4 2+21+41+71+13"
```

split to

```
$7,   $7,   +41,    +11,    +11,    +4,     2,    +21,    etc...
```

So I think the regex may be

```
([\$\+\s][0-9]?+)
```

Expressed in Java in this form:

```
"([\\$\\+\\s][0-9]?+)"
```

You can test this in this site

https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the problems of your implementation:

`[$][\d]|[\d][x(?=+)][x(?!\d)]|[\d]|[\D]`

- `[<stuff>]` brackets mean "find a *single* character that matches `<stuff>`" - it's mostly unnecessary for your case
- `[$][\d]` is not going to find anything: $ means "end-of-line", it wants to match "end-of-line and a digit"
- `[\d][x(?=+)][x(?!\d)]` it's hard to predict for me what this would match  - starts with a digit, then there is a "character x followed by 'nothing at least once'" (+ means at least once), and then "a character x not followed by a digit"
- `[\d]` - a digit
- `[\D]` - a non-digit character

And you "|" (OR) these together.

Conclusions:

- you need to escape special chars! `\$`, `\+`
- x() does nothing that you want
- most of the times it helps to think about and formulate  your problem in longer sequences rather than on character level

To rephrase your problem statement, you're looking to find these groups:

- $digit
- +digitdigit
- a character that is not `$` and not `+`

This class below does that:

```
public class Regex {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "$7$7+41+11+11+4 2+21+41+71+13!";
    Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile( "(\\$\\d)|(\\+\\d\\d)|([^\\$\\+])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }

  }

}
```

Outputs:

```
$7
$7
+41
+11
+11
4

2
+21
+41
+71
+13
!
```